# Flot: specify bar width for a single bar

Tags: flot

Im using `flotchart` to create a merged graph with lines and bars the graph is working properly but when i filter the graph by years there is just one x-axis and the bar fills the entire graphic. If i have more than one x-axis i don't have any problem.

I tried to change the barWidth property but if i put `barWidth : 0` the graphic stop filling but i get a extremely fine line to every bar... I just want to get a normal bar even with one x-axis.

Thanks!

Comment: Show some code please. Or even better create a simple Fiddle. Do you see some kind of errors in your console?

Comment: If you set `barWidth: 0` of course the bar is only a line (thats the border of the bar). Try something like `0.1` if you want just a thinner bar. If there is more to the problem, do as Rohan says.

Comment: @Raidri - Thanks by the answers, even if i set 0.1 or 0.0001 the graph will be filled entire.

Comment: @Rohan - No errors in console, is the normal behavior of the plugin. If u download the examples from here [Flot Examples](http://www.flotcharts.org/), and just edit the html file and change the inline javascript code like this:

`var data = [
  {"label":"Apple", "data": [[1,12]], "color":"#B41722"},
  {"label":"Samsang", "data":[[1,11]], "color":"#E78800"},
  {"label":"HTC", "data":[[1,10]], "color":"#83BA4F"}
 ];`
You can see what im talking about. Thanks a lot both :)

Comment: Which example are you pointing to directly? @AbrahamMesa